# Use of undeclared type with 2 view controllers - target memberships not working?

Tags: ios, types, viewcontroller, target, membership

In Xcode 7 Swift 2.0, my main view controller does not recognize a second view controller. All custom class names and storyboard IDs are set and I've also tried enabling the check beside class and tests under the target membership under the file inspector (tried checking just one and then checked both as well).

I'd really appreciate someone explaining step by step how to fix this? Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        var controller: DiceViewController // Error with this line: Use of undeclared type 'DiceViewController'
    }
}
```

I realize there are other posts here on StackOverFlow that are similar but they don't discuss if the target membership enabling still doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Have you actually created a custom class called DiceViewController, or did you just give it that name in the storyboard? Did you include said class in this file?

Comment: New to Xcode here .. thanks! that solved it!